# Python: Why does variables follow MRO

Tags: python, variables, inheritance

new to python...Why do methods follow MRO but, seemingly, variables dont

Specifically (apologies on formatting...first time on this sight):

```
class C1(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.value = 1

class C2(C1):
  def __init__(self):
    self.value = 2
    C1.__init__(self)

class C3(C2):
  def __init__(self):
    self.value = 3
    C2.__init__(self)

cc=C3()

cc.value  # or a bunch of other attempts at
```

No matter what I try, I always get the value of self.value in C1

How would one get the value of self.value in C2....C3???
or
why wouldn't all self.values be set to same (C1) value
(maybe its doing that ;-)  )

Comment: super gives C1 regardless

Comment: are you saying self.value in C1 takes precedent (no name scoping or MRO stuff)

Comment: ah...so you are saying that since same name, last __init__ sets final value?  Does that contradict name scoping since a local variable is being worked on in each layer...yet the final layer overrides all?

Comment: But they're *not* local variables. They all set attributes on the *same* instance.

Comment: but given version of self.value is inside the given version of  def __init__

Comment: shouldn't that namespace scope take precedent over some other class 3 hops back?

Comment: in general that would be like saying "don't need super construct...need a local construct for any variable inside a def".  E.g if its always some object far away for just this usage why not always far away and use some sort of "local" for a variable inside this def???

Comment: What namespace scope? What you're doing here is *exactly* the same as doing `self.value = 3; self.value = 2; self.value = 1`.

Comment: and even if this inheritance wasn't a hack, one should be able to delineate / identify some local variable vs the global variable 3 steps away.

Otherwise, mind a well prefix everything and don't bother with OO

class C1(object)

Comment: should the immediate __init__ running have its namescope higher priority than some grandparent class 3 hops away

Comment: I literally have no idea what you are doing, or why you think there are different scopes at all, or why you think this is a hack, or why you think this renders `super` useless. This is working exactly as intended, and in fact is the *whole point* of inheritance.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand why variables in an inheritance sequence behave different the other variables and functions.  I would have thought MRO would look locally before globally

Comment: **But they don't** behave differently and I can't understand why you think they do.

Comment: basically, because of this exception to namespace scope, one mind as well call everything unique and reengineer every time you use class somehere else

self.c1_value
self.c2_value
self.c3_value
c1_fcn()
c2_fcn()

Comment: because
a)  I can have self.value in different non inheritance class and rsolved

Comment: in fact the only way out of local scope in generic case is super
e.g  if no inheritance  then self.value in class 
x1 is different than self.value in class x2
and resolved as x1.value vs x2.value
same with functions

all works well until inheritance add...then x1.value = x2.value

Comment: appreciate the attempt to convince me inheritance is not a hack

will delineate variables and functions and namespace with prefixes

thx agan

Comment: I think the problem is that you seem to have completely misundersood what inheritance is. Until you fix that I don't think there's anything anyone can do to help you.

Comment: played with it more.  Yes, the only way to make scope work is to unique identify variables.   Functions are find (fcn of same name with different behaviors up through the chain of child, parent, grandparent behave according to respective behaviors).  But variables don't adhere to class scope...always back to the great grandfather class.   so yes cant enumerate a given variable....always have to have unique names if you want unique operations on a "local" variable.

So something like "local" or  "private" keywords would be useful since all the doc makes no mention of this subtle behavior.

Comment: There's no "subtle behaviour" going on. There is simply *assigning values*. If you want local variables, don't assign them to self. Note, this works the same way in every language.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* doing that, at least at first. But then you call `super`, and the code in that super class call overwrites the previous value.